Why does np.diff handle tz-naive and tz-aware indexes differently
I just noticed that np.diff treats tz-naive timestamps:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.diff(pd.DatetimeIndex(["2024-11-24", "2024-11-25"]))
==> array([86400000000000], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')

and tz-aware one:
np.diff(pd.DatetimeIndex(["2024-11-24 00:00 UTC", "2024-11-25 00:00 UTC"]))
==> array([Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00')], dtype=object)

differently.
Why?
(see also Why is tz-naive Timestamp converted to integer while tz-aware is kept as Timestamp?)

side-note, numpy does not store timezone information. Handling timezone-aware datetime as numpy datetime64 raises a deprecation warning since 1.11 (however not in your example afaik) and will cause an error in the future - numpy docs, end of this section.

@FObersteiner - thank you, i have numpy 2.1.3; and I am not storing datetime64 in numpy (at least I think np.diff does not convert DatetimeIndex to a  datetime64 numpy array.)

As for your question, my guess is that numpy encounters naive datetime in your example pt.1, where it can cast safely to its native datetime64 type, then calculate the timedelta. In pt.2, it encounters aware datetime, casting is prohibited, and it reaches for the existing __sub__ method of the array's elements. Didn't trace this, just an assumption; basically I do think that this different behavior in the two cases you describe comes down to numpy refusing to handle aware datetime. Might even play a role for your other question as well.
